# Count "gaps" between observations in R

Tags: r, count

I am having trouble with replicating a project that was done in Stata within R. One of the key snags I'm hitting is that I need to generate a variable that counts the number of years since a certain observation. Here's a simple recreation of what the data might look like:

> data <- cbind(1960:1970, c(NA, NA, 22, NA, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA,
>   22), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 4))

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] 1960   NA   NA
 [2,] 1961   NA   NA
 [3,] 1962   22   NA
 [4,] 1963   NA   NA
 [5,] 1964   NA   NA
 [6,] 1965   NA   NA
 [7,] 1966   24    4
 [8,] 1967   NA   NA
 [9,] 1968   NA   NA
[10,] 1969   NA   NA
[11,] 1970   22    4
```

I currently *have* the first two columns of `data` and I'm trying to automate the creation of column three with a function.

You can see that the third column is defined by the number of years between when values of the second column are *not* NAs but *only after* the first occurrence of the intervention (i.e. the second time column two has a value, but not the first).

If it's any help, here is the code in Stata that does this trick, where `since` is the third column in my simplified example. Basically this code is saying create new variable `since` that is defined as the number of years since there is a value in variable `redist` (second column in my example) after the first year there is a value in variable `redist`.

```
gen since=.
foreach n of numlist 1(1)10 {
    replace since = year - year[_n-`n'] if redist!=. & redist[_n-`n']!=. & since==.
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a column of `NA` values, then fill in the differences with a logical vector.  This assumes we begin with only the first two columns.

```
data <- cbind(data, NA)
nona <- !is.na(data[,2])
data[,3][nona] <- c(NA, diff(data[,1][nona]))

data
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 1960   NA   NA
# [2,] 1961   NA   NA
# [3,] 1962   22   NA
# [4,] 1963   NA   NA
# [5,] 1964   NA   NA
# [6,] 1965   NA   NA
# [7,] 1966   24    4
# [8,] 1967   NA   NA
# [9,] 1968   NA   NA
#[10,] 1969   NA   NA
#[11,] 1970   22    4
```